# Is this the only way in Django to access a ForeignKey related Model using the _meta fields API

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this code:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

Bar._meta.get_field('foo').rel.to
# returns 'Foo' class
```

The code is working, but is there another way to access the `Foo` Model class here?

It seems like there should be a cleaner API here, because this class is reaching deep into other objects by essentially doing `a.b.c.d`

In the code base where the code snippet is located, I only have access to the main model `Bar` class and the `field` by it's string name `'foo'`

Comment: Why exactly do you need access to Foo? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman there's a 3rd model that stores information and it has info about Bar and 'foo', the string name of Bar's field, but doesn't know what class the 'foo' field on Bar is unless doing something like the above to access it.